# Работа с посторонними файлами в python

Tags: python, json

Довольно странный вопрос. К примеру, я создал файл с моим собственным расширением - stck. Могу ли я пользоваться этим файлом в python не как со строкой, а как с файлами JSON? То есть, к примеру, там такой код:

```
{
"text": "qwerty"
}
```

если я буду работать с этим файлом как с обычным текстовым -

```py
with open('data.stck', "r+") as stckFile:
        strg = stckFile.read()
```

, то импортируется он как **строка**.
Мне же необходимо работать с ним как с объектом (к примеру).

Подскажите, есть ли какое-либо решение, кроме как переписать модуль, встроенный в язык - json по свою гребенку?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. В Вашем примере самый обычный json.

Comment: это пример. Я выбрал именно этот, чтобы к переменной после прочтения файла можно было сразу же присвоить словарь.

Comment: имеется в виду экспорт текста из какого-либо файла, однако так, чтобы работать с ни можно было не **как со строкой**, а как с **кодом**

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно. Как с каким кодом?

Comment: к примеру, при экспорте информации из файла .json посредством функции json.load(), мы можем присвоить этот "файл" переменной (a = json.load()) и впоследствии обращаться с переменной как со списком/словарем/и т д.

Comment: Меня интересует, возможна ли аналогичная операция с другими файлами.

Comment: Если это не какой-то стандарт, а что-то придуманное Вами, то только писать собственный кодер/декодер. Вряд ли кто-то написал кодер/декодер для того, что пришло Вам в голову. Если Ваш файл по структуре похож на json, то можно унаследоваться от [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)/[`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) и переписать под свои нужды.

Comment: что ж, спасибо за совет. пойду писать пакет.

Comment: Возможно, Вы привели недостаточно информации. По настоящим входным данным и ожидаемой реакции, может быть, получиться точнее понять, что Вы хотите.

Comment: Уточните вопрос о каких файлах идет речь. Если вам нужна сериализация/десериализация объектов __любого__ типа в/из файла, то для этого существует встроенный модуль `pickle`.

Comment: exec, pickle???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй стандартную библиотеку json.
Чтобы получить json (словарь в Python) используется класс JSONDecoder.

Пример:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('data.stck') as f:
...    string_from_file = f.read().replace('\n', '')
...
>>> string_from_file
'{"text": "qwerty"}'
>>> dec = json.JSONDecoder()
>>> j = dec.raw_decode(string_from_file)[0]
>>> j
{'text': 'qwerty'}
>>> j['text']
'qwerty'
```

Answer (score 1):

Расширение файла не имеет значения (это просто часть имени) - важно содержимое. Если содержимое файла является корректным json, то с файлом можно работать с помощью модуля json:

```
import json

with open('data.stck', "r+") as stckFile:
    strg = json.load(stckFile)
    # или strg = json.loads(stckFile.read())
```